# Explanation in the following step

Tags: real-analysis

There is a passage in my book that I can't grasp. Let $H$ be the Heaviside's step function and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R^+}$, then
$$\int_0^\infty H(f(x)-t)\,dt=\int_0^{f(x)}dt,\qquad t\ge0.$$

Intuitevly,  I think that $H$ is simply tracing the region where $f(x)>t$, but how did they make this step mathematically?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is everywhere nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question.

Comment: You might want to think, then, about why that assumption is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some leading questions**

1. For which values of $u$ is $H(u) = 1$?
2. For which values of $f(x) -t $ is $H(f(x) - t))= 1$?
3. Fixing $x$ for the moment, for which values of $t$ is $H(f(x) - t) = 1$?
4. The integrand on the left hand side is always either $0$ or $1$. On which interval is it $1$?
5. What is the length of that integral?
6. How is that related to the integral on the right-hand side?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea with tracing where $f(x)>t$ is correct.
To show that, you could split the integral at $f(x)$ in two parts:

$$\int_0^\infty H(f(x)-t)\;dt = \int_0^{f(x)} H(f(x)-t)\;dt + \int_{f(x)}^\infty H(f(x)-t)\;dt$$

Then you can see that the function inside the left integral is constant $1$ (because $f(x)-t > 0$ for all $t\in (0,f(x))$) and the function inside the right integral is constant $0$ (because $f(x)-t < 0$ for all $t\in (f(x),\infty)$).